# Scanline fill algorithm using odd/parity rule

Tags: algorithm, scanline

[image: http://s14.postimage.org/br35lkb9d/Untitled.png]

The question is this:
Number the rows and columns in the following figure (outside the figure). Use these row column numbers to show how the scanline stack region filling algorithm would fill in this figure, starting at the pixel indicated. Show the contents of the stack at each phase of the algorithm and show the location in the figure of the pixels on the stack.

Since row 0 is already filled moving to 
row 1, it's fairly simple that party turns odd at (0,1) and fills until it turns even again at (12,1)
row 2. (0,2) triggers parity odd so it fills the next 2 pixels. at (3,2), I'm confused between the rule "vertices on horizontal line does not count" vs "count vertex if it's Ymin of that". How do I proceed at this part? and how will the rest of pixel should be treated? All the examples I could find concerning those two rules involves polygons with pointy vertices, not like the one I uploaded.